# How to set TabFocus to QRadioButtons and set them into 2 columns

Tags: qt, tabs, focus, radio-group

I’m making a gui app with Qt 4.8.5 which goes with keyboard interaction so all the logic between widgets its throw TabFocus. I found a problem when I tried to put 4 radiobuttons and see that you have to use arrows instead of tab and spacebar so searching a little bit I found this example about how to do it with tab: [EXAMPLE](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Button_groups_with_tab_focus)

I added this new class “CustomButtonGroup” and applied it BUT I have another problem which is: I have 4 radiobuttons and I need them to be in 2 different columns (qrb_1 and qrb_2 on the left side, and qrb_3 and qrn_4 on the right one). To do that I used some layouts like this:

- VlayQRB: where I have another widget upside the radiobuttons and then
  the Hlay2
- Hlay2: to add 2 vboxlayouts to divide the radiobuttons into
  2 columns
- Vlay2L: for qrb_1 and qrb_2
- Vlay2R: for qrb_3 and qrb_4

  ```
  VlayQRB->addLayout(Hlay2);
  Hlay2->addLayout(Vlay2L);  
  Hlay2->addLayout(Vlay2R); 


  Vlay2L->addWidget(qrb_1);
  Vlay2L->addWidget(qrb_2);
  Vlay2R->addWidget(qrb_3);
  Vlay2R->addWidget(qrb_4);
  CustomButtonGroup *cBG = new CustomButtonGroup;
  qrb_1 = new QRadioButton(QString::fromUtf8(" Hi 1"));
  qrb_2= new QRadioButton(QString::fromUtf8(" Hi 2"));
  qrb_3 = new QRadioButton(QString::fromUtf8(" Hi 3"));
  qrb_4 = new QRadioButton(QString::fromUtf8(" HI 4"));

  cBG->addButton(qrb_1);
  cBG->addButton(qrb_2);
  cBG->addButton(qrb_3);
  cBG->addButton(qrb_4);
  ```

The problem is that if I do that, the program closes unexpectly when I press space on a radiobutton BUT it works really fine if I only put qrb_1 and qrb_2 so I suppose that the program is becoming crazy with all that logic between so many layouts.

Any idea of how can I apply the CustomButtonGroup (which gaves me the logic about tab and spacebar I need) to my case (I need 4 radio buttons in 2 colums so I have 2 buttons on the right and 2 buttons on the left)??

Note: I tried too, creating a second CustomGroupBox and adding there qrb_3 and qrb_4 and it works fine but then, of course, I have 2 options checked on true (one for each custombuttongroup)

Thank you so much.

Comment: do you not have access to designer?

Comment: I do it all with code, not with the ui.

Comment: There seems to be nothing wrong with this so your error must be elsewhere, unless your not setting VLayQRB to your main widget

Comment: The problem may be here because as I said, if I create a second CustomButtonGroup and add the 2 last radiobuttons (which are in another vlayout  than the 2 first) then it goes well but of course I can choose 2 options at once. Moreover, if I have that 4 radio buttons in 2 layouts the program crashes (if I put the 4 in VLAY2L it works well). That is why I suppose that the problem is between all that layouts and the rabiobuttons' logic

Comment: why not just use a grid layout then?

Comment: Didn't thought about that widget. It can solve my problem I think so I'll try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See QGrid Layout since its a single layout your button group should work as expected 
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgridlayout.html